# Java / C# Почему одна функция с одинаковыми параметрами показывает разное время выполнения?

Tags: java, c#

Во время написания программы у меня возник вопрос, ответ на который я не смог найти.
Я замеряю время выполнения одной функции в наносекундах с одинаковыми параметрами и получаю не одинаковый результат (на Java):

`-- 0,000087036
 -- 0,000084647
 -- 0,000082940
 -- 0,000101713
 -- 0,000085330
 -- 0,000087377
 -- 0,000082598
 -- 0,000085330
 -- 0,000081916
 -- 0,000084306
 -- 0,000081916
 -- 0,000082940
 -- 0,000083622
 -- 0,000083964
 -- 0,000081916
 -- 0,000081575
 -- 0,000095227
 -- 0,000081916
 -- 0,000087036
 -- 0,000081575
Среднее значение -- 0,000085244`

Я пробовал делать то же самое на C#, там тоже значения не одинаковые. Возможно, это очевидно, что они не могут совпадать из-за очень высокой точности времени, но хотелось бы узнать конкретную причину. Как это можно объяснить? Что на это влияет?
Код Java:

```
public class MainFloat {
final static int RAND_MAX = 32767;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] check = new int[] {1000, 5000, 10000, 20000, 30000, 40000, 50000, 60000, 70000, 80000, 90000, 100000, 200000, 300000,
            400000, 500000, 600000, 700000, 800000, 900000, 1000000, 2500000, 5000000, 10000000, 15000000, 20000000};
    double counter = 0;
    double timeSpent = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        int N = check[i];
        float[] a = new float[N];
        float[] b = new float[N];
        float[] c = new float[N];
        float[] f = new float[N];
        float[] x = new float[N];
        for(int h = 1; h <= N - 1; h++) {
            do {
                a[h] = (float) ((h == 1) ? 0 : Math.random() * RAND_MAX);
                b[h] = (float) ((h == N - 1) ? 0 : Math.random() * RAND_MAX);
                c[h] = (float) (Math.random() * RAND_MAX);
            } while(Math.abs(c[h]) < Math.abs(a[h]) + Math.abs(b[h]));
            f[h] = (float) (Math.random() * RAND_MAX);
        }
        counter = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
            double startTime = System.nanoTime();
            Progonka(check[i] - 1, a, b, c, f, x);
            timeSpent = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
            System.out.printf(" -- %8.9f%n", timeSpent/1000000000);
            counter += timeSpent/1000000000;
        }
        counter /= 20;
        System.out.printf("%8.9f%n", counter);
    }
    System.out.printf("END");
}
static void Progonka(int np, float ap[], float bp[], float cp[], float fp[], float xp[]) {
    float[] alfa = new float[np + 1];
    float[] beta = new float[np + 1];
    int ip;
    for(ip = 1; ip < np; ip++) {
        alfa[ip + 1] = bp[ip] / (cp[ip] - ap[ip] * alfa[ip]);
        beta[ip + 1] = (fp[ip] + ap[ip] * beta[ip]) / (cp[ip] - ap[ip] * alfa[ip]);
    }
    xp[np] = (fp[np] + ap[np] * beta[np]) / (cp[np] - ap[np] - alfa[np]);
    for(ip = np - 1; ip >= 1; ip--)
        xp[ip] = alfa[ip + 1] * xp[ip + 1] + beta[ip + 1];
}
```

}

Comment: Мне кажется вопрос глупый по той причине, что нагрузка ЦП в разные моменты времени, разная. Отсюда у вас и будет разное время выполнения, к тому же, на такой точности

Comment: Как уже сказали - конкурентная среда выполнения процесса, "горячие" оптимизации виртуальных машин, разного рода кэши.

Comment: Я не согласен с тем, что вопрос глупый. По моему вопрос наоборот очень полезный. Вообще измерение производительности - очень сложная тема. Скорость выполнения метода может зависеть от массы факторов. Например, первый запуск метода в .NET может быть очень медленным, так как будет происходить компилция метода. После этого запуски могут быть более-менее одинаковые, но не стоит ожидать совпадения в наносекундах, так как, как уже было сказано, у вас может параллельно что то работать (GC, например, или другие процессы) и грузить этим систему.

Comment: Всем большое спасибо) я получил требуемый ответ